# Unable to convert a lead if country if country is not defalut country

Tags: leads, country-and-state

few dacks back we have enabled country & state picklist values.

So, when trying to convert a lead with a country called Canada they are facing an issue. because currently, the default country is the United States.

As per debug logs:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, There's a problem with this state,
>   even though it may appear correct. Please select a state from the list
>   of valid states.: Shipping State/Province: [ShippingState]

I have tried a few things:

```
1.Updated default country to none
2.Updated organization country to none
3.Tried to map fields(State & others) via process builder
```

But no luck.So, could you please help me on this.

Comment: Could you check if state/country picklists are enabled? Probably just need to rescan customizatins and data in Setup->Data->State and Country/Territory Picklists

Comment: What's in the State field on that lead record?

Comment: To both the above comments, please see that the OP wrote: "we have enabled country & state picklist values" so 1. State/country picklists are enabled, and 2. The State field is the Lead State picklist field.